# Visual Studio Designing overlapping panels

Tags: c#, .net, panel, windows-forms-designer

I have about 4 panels that are overlapping eachother and I need to be able to make changes to each one.
When I select panel 1 and try bring to front, and then click on the panel, it's just keeps panel 4 in front.

Same deal with rightclicking panel 4 and doing send to back. I click the panel and it's still in front.

How do people normally deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: Use the "Document Outline" window and bring the panel you want to work on to the front.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that one, that helps a lot! Thanks! Turns out I actually had my panels placed inside eachother and that was the reason I couldn't bring anything to the front or back

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, and thanks to @CodyGray for the comment, which is a viable solution. But once I became aware that the four-headed arrow didn't necessarily represent the panel that you see I've determined that the Document Outline window isn't necessary to bring a different panel to the front. Just selecting the panel in the selector list at the top of the Properties window is enough to cause the four-headed arrow to be associated with the panel you want to bring to the front.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, selection can be made through the combo listing the components at the properties page.

For further references I want to add a strategy helpful for overlapping panels at design time. Desired position of the panels can be recorded and the location properties of the panels not of interest can be set to a location out of the panels. After the design, location property of the moved panels are set back to their original location.